# How can I swap two records from particular column in a table in PSQL?

Tags: psql

Consider a table test contains attributes of id and name.

The values for that.

Id   | Name

1    | Raj

2    | Kumar

From the above sample table, I know the id only, So through the Id I need to swap the name, like given below,

Id   | Name

1    | Kumar

2    | Raj

Comment: Is there only two records?

Comment: No there will be many records.

Comment: So what to replace with what?

Comment: The above one is just for example...

Comment: I need to swap the particular record in the name column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update test
    set name = case id
        when 1 then (select name from test where id = 2)
        when 2 then (select name from test where id = 1)
    end
where id in (1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can swap two values from a particular row by using the 'With Query'.
Using 'with' we can take the back and use it.
The query to solve the requirement,

`with backup1 as (select name from test where id = 2), backup2 as (update test set name = (select name from test where id = 1) where id = 2)
update test set name = (select * from backup1) where id = 1;`

In the above query, the backup1 contains the name of whose id is 2, After that using update query I took the name of whose id is 1 and
stored in the name field where id is 2.
Then again using the update query I took the name from the backup and stored in the name field where id is 1, Like this we can swap.